# Why does a serve and a fluiduct not extract creosote oil from coke oven

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I have 6 coke ovens producing coal coke but i cant seem to figure out why 9it wont work, in in 1.7.10 survival stories 3 (and no the tank is not full that tank goes up a lot) The coke ovens are from railcraft the fluiducts from thermal dynamics and the tank is from openblocks
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Welcome, could you specify what mod you are using by [editing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/382160/edit) the post?

Comment: To whoever is voting to close, this isn't asking for technical support. If anything it should be closed for a lack of detail in the mod used.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear due to the lack of mod specification.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your fluiduct isnt turned on. the Red part of the pipe is very dark. Give it a redstone signal, or configure it with a modwrench(i forgot which one), and it should light up and start pumping out.

Answer (score -1):

General rule of mods: Mods generally **DO NOT WORK WITH EACH OTHER** (unless they're part of one of those group modpacks, like Technic or FTB). The Fluiducts and Tanks work because Thermal Dynamics and OpenBlocks use a common API for fluid transfers, whereas Railcraft does not use it, and thus are not compatible with the ducts or tanks.

Whilst Fluiducts do work with the tanks, the coke ovens do not work with the fluiducts. You have to manually bucket it.